# Delete strings with non-Ukrainian characters bash

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed

Using file structure

```
foo_11: "Марія"
foo_112: "Superman"
FOOTLONG: "Subway"
foo_13: "Юлія"
```

I want to remove all strings that **don't have** at least one character from  Ukrainian alphabet.

Script:

```
for i in *.txt;
do 
 sed '/[^А-ЯЄЇІа-яєїі]+/d' $i >$i.out
 mv $i.out $i
done
```

doesn't do anything. What is wrong?

Using mac bash.

Comment: does your sed support the `+` modifier? Mine doesn't, so I'd have to write `\{1,\}` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your character class defining Ukrainian letters is correct, the following should work:

```
sed '/[А-ЯЄЇІа-яєїі]/!d' file
```

- `[А-ЯЄЇІа-яєїі]` matches a Ukrainian letter anywhere on the line.

  - Note that even the letters that *look* like ASCII letters `A I a i` are actually *Ukrainian* (Cyrillic) letters with Unicode codepoints `U+410 U+406 U+430 U+456`.
- `!` negates the match, meaning that only lines *not* containing at least 1 Ukrainian letter match.
- `d` deletes those lines.

To put it all together:

```
for f in *.txt; do 
  sed -i '' '/[А-ЯЄЇІа-яєїі]/!d' "$f"    # -i '' is BSD Sed syntax; GNU sed takes just -i
done
```

---

As for what you've tried:

- As @StefanHegny points out in a comment on the question, `+` isn't supported when `sed` is *not* run with `-E` in order to enable *extended* regular expressions; without `-E`, the cumbersome `\{1,\}` must be used. (`\+` is only supported by *GNU* `sed`, not by the BSD version of `sed` that macOS comes with).
- However, even the fixed version of your command, `sed '/[^А-ЯЄЇІа-яєїі]\{1,\}/d'`, doesn't do what you want: it deletes all lines that contain *at least one non-Ukrainian-letter character*, which eliminates *all* of your input lines, given that they all have ASCII-based field names and contain `:`.
- You should double-quote variable references such as `$i` to protect them from shell expansions: `"$i"`
- BSD Sed does support in-place updating with `-i`, but - unlike GNU Sed - it requires that an empty option-argument (indicating that no backup of the input file should be made) be specified *as a separate argument*: `-i ''`.

  - Your write-to-a-temp-file-first-then-replace-the-original approach works too, but it's generally better to use the following idiom: `sed ... file > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file`. Separating the `mv` command with `&&` ensures that the original file is only replaced if the `sed` command succeeded.
    That said, that doesn't help with logic errors as in the case at hand: despite outputting nothing, `sed` reports success in this case.

Comment: Your answer is probably better than mine because it avoid the `mv` part, so I voted you up.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However, I didn't have to use `sed -i ''`, even though I didn't create an alias, somehow, regular `sed` worked just fine in this case. I had to use the abovementioned workaround in other cases though...

Comment: Also, at the beginning of every file I have string _l_ukrainian:_ not sure why it was not removed by the script, even though it suits me well.

Comment: @mklement0 you probably misread ` l_ukrainian ` was NOT removed in my case. That's what surprised me.

Comment: @AlCrow: Ah, I see. That is indeed surprising. Pipe your files to `cat -v` and see if there are any Ukrainian chars. in that first line after all (such as a `U+456`  `i`). (But it sounds like you actually _want_ to keep that line, right?)

Comment: @mklement0 `cat -v` on that string displayed only one extra character - `^M`. Not sure why it's in the specified range... I do want to keep it but would like to have more control on what the script is up to.

Comment: Just for the record, ` l_ukrainian ` is not removed even when it doesn't contain Carriage Return `^M`.

Comment: @AlCrow: Very curious - I cannot reproduce this. If you want to get to the bottom of this, I suggest you post a _new_ question, with the exact file contents (the first few lines).

Answer (score 2):

This code would achieve what you want (if I understood your question correctly):

```
grep -i "Я\|Є\|Ї\|І" /folder/file >> /tmp/result
```

The result is stored on `/tmp/result`

**Note: I don't know Ukranian, so I'm sure I did not included all Ukranian characters, please add/delete Ukranian characters you want to match to the construction above.**

**Note2:** this code is case insensitive thanks to `grep -i` so you only need to add the character once (lowercase or capital).

To put it on your loop it could be:

```
for i in *.txt;
do
grep -i "Я\|Є\|Ї\|І" "$i" > "$i".out
mv "$i".out "$i"
done
```

**Edit:** I edited this answer to make it simpler, and to add a loop to it.

Comment: Even the letters that _look_ like ASCII letters `A I a i` in the OP's character class are actually _Ukrainian_ (Cyrillic) letters with Unicode codepoints `U+410 U+406 U+430 U+456`

Comment: I see. I wasn't sure, Ukranian is not really my strong suit :-p

Comment: I will leave to the OP to add all the Ukranian characters.

Comment: @JamilSaid you did the letters right) you just forgot to include the range **А-Я**. I read somewhere on the _Stack_ that above range includes only Russian letters so I used this workaround adding some missing letters. One should, probably, also include **Ґ** but this suits my case though.